# Modem+Router+Switch+Router connection in a LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, switch

**What I am trying to do:**
I have 2000 users in a region. I have one modem and from that I connect a router now router can only grant access to the IPs between 192.168.0.1-255 BUT my users are 2000 what should I do to achieve this. I need to establish connection between all the device connected to the main router.  *Here Communication means to transfer messages and files back and forth*.

Approach: To increase number of users, i connect more then 1 router but communication is not being established

I am having the connection as shown in image below,
[image]

I am trying to send message(utility is running like IPMessenger on all the PCs) from PC connected to Lynksys to the PC connected to TP-Link.

Problem is that I am not able to do the same.
The IP address of the Lynksys PC is not in the range of 192.168.1.* , it is showing the IP in the range of 192.168.0.*.

Comment: You just have to increase the size of your network. [192.168.0.0/21](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.0.1&mask1=21&mask2=) should give you a bit more than 2k addresses. Read up on "Subnet Masks" and such and try telling your router to give out addresses for such a network.

Comment: @TheUser1024 ; So after sub-netting, will I be able to transfer data from Lynksys PC to TP-Link PC? and after that if i can increase the number of users using sub-netting on TP-Link then there is no use of Lynksys router.

Comment: Exactly, it simply becomes one network.

Comment: @TheUser1024 But my requirement is to connect more than one router to the first router connected to the modem. After connecting multiple routers I want to establish communication between PCs

Comment: Actually I devided 2k addresses in the group of 100 and on each 100, i want to fix routers and then establish the connection between all 2k PCs

Comment: I am connecting more routers because my network area is very wide so to enhance the signal strength I need to do so.If any other idea you are having please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last comment I take it you try to build a WLAN network. With the right equipment (which you should have if you have 2000 users) this would still be only one network. Maybe you would be best served, if you try to build this in a simulated environment with http://www.gns3.net/ or the https://www.netacad.com/web/about-us/cisco-packet-tracer

Anyhow, to execute your chosen solution: Configure the interfaces connected to the switch to be within one network, e.g. 192.168.100.0/24. Now the routers can talk to each other on layer 3. Configure the other interface (or interfaces) to be within another network, e.g. 192.168.200.0/24. Now your clients on this router must be in 192.168.200.0/24 also. Now your clients can talk to your router and to other clients in 192.168.200.0/24 on layer 3. Repeat this step for all routers but choose different networks, e.g. 192.168.201.0/24 and so on. (This is not strictly necessary but I think it makes things easier to grasp.) Set the router as the default gateway for your clients in the respective networks and the traffic from one network can route to the other networks and vice versa. To get internet access configure the router with the WAN connection to be the default gateway of the other routers.

Please note that if you are thinking about providing services from one network for the others, your routers must provide DNAT (ie. port forwarding.)